# python multiple logical or conditions in where statement

Tags: python, numpy, logical-or

I am trying to determine boundary node indices in a 2D domain using the following python code,

```
import numpy as np
...
b_index0 = np.where( (nodeDat[:,2] == xu) or
                     (nodeDat[:,2] == xl) or
                     (nodeDat[:,3] == yu) or
                     (nodeDat[:,3] == yl) )
```

where `nodeDate[:,2]` and `nodeDat[:3]` are lists of floating point `x` and `y` values respectively.
This produces the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried a number of variations using np.add() and np.all(), but none seemed to work.

If I use `|` instead of `or`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200) into shape (1)
```

By experimentation, I found that the following code generates a correct list of 200 indices, which is the answer I require :

```
b_index00 = np.where(nodeDat[:,2] == xu)
b_index01 = np.where(nodeDat[:,2] == xl)    
b_index02 = np.where(nodeDat[:,3] == yu)
b_index03 = np.where(nodeDat[:,3] == yl)

b_index0 = np.unique(np.hstack((b_index00, b_index01,b_index02, b_index03)))
```

However, this seems to be an inefficient/inelegant way of achieving the desired result. It also produces duplicate indices, hence the call to `np.unique()`.

The following suggested link provides some background as to why the initial code does not work, but does not appear to provide a solution to my particular problem.
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: use the `|` operator instead of `or`

Comment: Using the '|' instead of 'or' gives the following error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200) into shape (1).I have also updated the question regarding np.any() and 'np.all()'.

Comment: The `|` should work. The broadcast error suggests something funny or inconsistent about the `nodeDat` array.

Comment: Test the condition logic by itself, without the `where` call. Python evaluates that array first.  where just finds the true elements.